# Need to convert json to xml in titanium

Tags: javascript

can any one please let me know how to convert json data to XML in titanium

Example JSON Data :

```
{
   msg: {
       tile:"tname",
       description:"tdescr"
  }
}
```

to XML as

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <msg title="name" description="tdescr" />
```

Thanks in Advance,

Swathi

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48788722/453767) for your own solution. However using some library like json2xml, xml2js, [fast-xml-parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser) can be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a generic JavaScript question, without any peculiarities for Titanium. If you thus broaden your thinking about it, you'll find a ton of libraries that do exactly what you want -- create XML from a vanilla JavaScript object.

There's a popular library x2js, for instance:

https://github.com/abdmob/x2js

Or simply search your favorite engine (or StackOverflow) for "javascript json to xml".