# JSON to XML Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xml

I am trying to convert the JSON to XML  but not getting exact output.In My JSON having array object it not converting that to XML array.Mainly   array object is not converting into XML as expected

```js
var InputJSON = "{"body":{"entry": [{ "fullURL" : "abcd","Resource": "1234"},{ "fullURL" : "efgh","Resource": "5678"}]}}";
var output = eval("OBJtoXML("+InputJSON+");")

function OBJtoXML(obj) {
    var xml = '';
    for (var prop in obj) {
        xml += "<" + prop + ">";
        if(obj[prop] instanceof Array) {
            for (var array in obj[prop]) {
                xml += OBJtoXML(new Object(obj[prop][array]));
            }
        } else if (typeof obj[prop] == "object") {
            xml += OBJtoXML(new Object(obj[prop]));
        } else {
            xml += obj[prop];
        }
        xml += "</" + prop + ">";
    }
    var xml = xml.replace(/<\/?[0-9]{1,}>/g,'');
    return xml
}
```

Actual Output:

```
<body>
  <entry>
    <fullURL>abcd</fullURL>
    <Resource>1234</Resource>
    <fullURL>efgh</fullURL>
    <Resource>5678</Resource>
  </entry>
</body>
```

Expected Output:

```
<body>
  <entry>
    <fullURL>abcd</fullURL>
    <Resource>1234</Resource>
  </entry>
 <entry>
    <fullURL>efgh</fullURL>
    <Resource>5678</Resource>
  </entry>
</body>
```

Please guide me if i am missing anything from the code to get my expected result

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1773550

Comment: better if you provide valid JSON
`var InputJSON = "{"body":{"entry": [{ "fullURL" : "abcd","Resource": "1234"},{ "fullURL" : "efgh","Resource": "5678"}]}}"` is not a valid json

Comment: Thanks Usman your promt response.But i have checked the JSON fro mjson parser its valid only and also i need to convert without any parser and serializer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

replace your `OBJtoXML` function with

```
function OBJtoXML(obj) {
  var xml = '';
  for (var prop in obj) {
    xml += obj[prop] instanceof Array ? '' : "<" + prop + ">";
    if (obj[prop] instanceof Array) {
      for (var array in obj[prop]) {
        xml += "<" + prop + ">";
        xml += OBJtoXML(new Object(obj[prop][array]));
        xml += "</" + prop + ">";
      }
    } else if (typeof obj[prop] == "object") {
      xml += OBJtoXML(new Object(obj[prop]));
    } else {
      xml += obj[prop];
    }
    xml += obj[prop] instanceof Array ? '' : "</" + prop + ">";
  }
  var xml = xml.replace(/<\/?[0-9]{1,}>/g, '');
  return xml
}
```

Comment: Great Usman it works as expected...Thanks for your prompt response.. :)

Comment: this doesn't work if the attribute or property contains a slash.   fore example a json property of "team/stats" wont work as it will be converted to <team/stats> which is invalid xml.

Comment: Won't work with & which would have to be converted to &amp; and otherwise prevent XML processing.

Answer (score 5):

Using [xml-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js) lib

```js
import { json2xml } from "xml-js";

const input = {
  contact: {
    name: `John & cia "example"`
  }
};
const xml = json2xml(input, {
  compact: true
});

// <contact><name>John &amp; cia \"example\"</name></contact>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/xml-json-forked-zgit4?file=/src/index.js:97-103

:)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems here, for starters, here the JSON string variable either needs to have it's quotes escaped. Or be wrapped in single quotes. For example:

```
var InputJSON = '{"body":{"entry": [{ "fullURL" : "abcd","Resource": "1234"},{ "fullURL" : "efgh","Resource": "5678"}]}}';
```

Next, there is no need to use `eval` here, when using JSON in JavaScript you should use `JSON.parse`

```
// First parse the JSON
var InputJSON = JSON.parse(InputJSON);

// Now execute the 'OBJtoXML' function
var output = OBJtoXML(InputJSON);
```

Now we come to the meat of this question, why is `entry` only occuring once?
The problem that you're having is that `xml += "<" + prop + ">";` and `xml += "</" + prop + ">";` are only happening once per property.
A possible solution would look like this:

```js
function OBJtoXML(obj) {
    var xml = '';
    for (var prop in obj) {
        xml += "<" + prop + ">";
        if(Array.isArray(obj[prop])) {
            for (var array of obj[prop]) {

                // A real botch fix here
                xml += "</" + prop + ">";
                xml += "<" + prop + ">";

                xml += OBJtoXML(new Object(array));
            }
        } else if (typeof obj[prop] == "object") {
            xml += OBJtoXML(new Object(obj[prop]));
        } else {
            xml += obj[prop];
        }
        xml += "</" + prop + ">";
    }
    var xml = xml.replace(/<\/?[0-9]{1,}>/g,'');
    return xml
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Xml-to-json](https://github.com/javadev/xml-to-json) library has methods `jsonToXml(json)` and `xmlToJson(xml)`.

https://xmltojson.github.io

```
var inputJSON = '{"body":{"entry": [{ "fullURL" : "abcd","Resource": "1234"},{ "fullURL" : "efgh","Resource": "5678"}]}}';

var xml = jsonToXml(inputJSON);

// <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
// <body>
//   <entry>
//     <fullURL>abcd</fullURL>
//     <Resource>1234</Resource>
//   </entry>
//   <entry>
//     <fullURL>efgh</fullURL>
//     <Resource>5678</Resource>
//   </entry>
// </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputJSON = '{"body":{"entry": [{ "fullURL" : "abcd","Resource": "1234"},{ "fullURL" : "efgh","Resource": "5678"}]}}';
var parsedInput = JSON.parse(inputJSON);

function OBJtoXML(obj) {
    var xml = '';
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj[prop] instanceof Array) {
            for (var array in obj[prop]) {
                xml += '<' + prop + '>';
                xml += OBJtoXML(new Object(obj[prop][array]));
                xml += '</' + prop + '>';
            }
        } else {
            xml += '<' + prop + '>';
            typeof obj[prop] == 'object' ? xml += OBJtoXML(new Object(obj[prop])) : xml += obj[prop];
            xml += '</' + prop + '>';
        }
    }
    var xml = xml.replace(/<\/?[0-9]{1,}>/g, '');
    return xml;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Anderi  Ros.Here i am trying without any inbuild libraries to parse the JSON.So i have used "eval".

Answer (score 0):

```
function OBJtoXML(obj, index) {
    var xml = '', 
        root, 
        count = 0;
    if (index > 0) count = index;
    for (var prop in obj) {
      switch (typeof obj[prop]) {
          case 'object': {
              if(obj[prop] instanceof Array) {
                  for (var instance in obj[prop]) {
                    xml += `\n\t<${prop}>\n${OBJtoXML(new Object(obj[prop][instance]))}\t</${prop}>`;
                  }
              }
              else {
                  if (count === 0) {
                    // console.log(`Setting root: ${prop}`)
                    root = prop
                  }
                  xml += `<${prop}>${OBJtoXML(new Object(obj[prop]), count)}\n</${prop}>\n`;
              }
              break;
          }
          case 'number':
          case 'string': {
              // console.log(`Setting ${typeof obj[prop]}`)
              xml += `\t\t<${prop}>${obj[prop]}</${prop}>\n`;
              break;
          }
      }
      count += 1;
    }
    return xml
}

var InputJSON = '{"body":{"entry": [{ "fullURL" : "abcd","Resource": "1234"},{ "fullURL" : "efgh","Resource": "5678"}]}}';
var output = eval("OBJtoXML("+InputJSON+");");
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const objectToXml = (object) => Object.keys(object).reduce((reqStr, key) => {
  const value = object[key] || '';
  const isObject = typeof value === 'object';
  const isArray = Array.isArray(value);
  if (isArray) {
    return reqStr + value.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) =>
      accumulator + `<${key}>${ typeof currentValue === 'object' ? objectToXml(currentValue) : (currentValue || '')}</${key}>`
    ,'');
  }
  if (isObject) {
    return reqStr + `<${key}>${objectToXml(value)}</${key}>`;
  }
  return reqStr + `<${key}>${value}</${key}>`;
}, '');       

const output = objectToXml(yourJson);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Object/Array to XML converter

The following solution can turn a JS variable to a (non indented) XML string. It supports both lists (arrays) and objects.

- Use `objectToXml(object)` to create a valid XML with a single root element.
- Use `variableToXml(variable, 'listElementName')` if you want to convert an array of elements. In this case, you have to pass the tag name for the list elements as the second argument.

```js
function objectToXml(object) {
  if (object instanceof Array || Object.keys(object).length !== 1) {
    throw 'variable has to be an object with a single property'
  }
  return variableToXml(object)
}

function variableToXml(variable, arrayItemPropertyName = null) {
  if (Array.isArray(variable)) {
    return variable.reduce((xml, propertyValue) => {
      const value = variableToXml(propertyValue)
      return `${xml}<${arrayItemPropertyName}>${value}</${arrayItemPropertyName}>`
    }, '')
  }
  if (variable instanceof Object) {
    return Object.entries(variable).reduce((xml, [propertyName, propertyValue]) => {
      const value = variableToXml(propertyValue, propertyName )
      const tag = propertyValue instanceof Array ? value : `<${propertyName}>${value}</${propertyName}>`
      return `${xml}${tag}`
    }, '')
  }
  return variable
}
```

### Input variable

```js
const object = {
  rootTag: {
    intProperty: 4,
    stringProperty: 'foo',
    listOfElements: {
      element: [{
        intProperty: 5,
        stringProperty: 'bar',
      }, {
        intProperty: 5,
        stringProperty: 'bar',
      }],
    },
    list: {
      listElement: [1, 2, 3],
    },
  },
}
```

### Output XML (prettified)

```xml
<rootTag>
  <intProperty>4</intProperty>
  <stringProperty>foo</stringProperty>
  <listOfElements>
    <element>
      <intProperty>5</intProperty>
      <stringProperty>bar</stringProperty>
    </element>
    <element>
      <intProperty>5</intProperty>
      <stringProperty>bar</stringProperty>
    </element>
  </listOfElements>
  <list>
    <listElement>1</listElement>
    <listElement>2</listElement>
    <listElement>3</listElement>
  </list>
</rootTag>
```

### Demo

```js
const object = {
  rootTag: {
    intProperty: 4,
    stringProperty: 'foo',
    listOfElements: {
      element: [{
        intProperty: 5,
        stringProperty: 'bar',
      }, {
        intProperty: 5,
        stringProperty: 'bar',
      }],
    },
    list: {
      listElement: [1, 2, 3],
    },
  },
}

console.log(objectToXml(object))

function objectToXml(object) {
  if (object instanceof Array || Object.keys(object).length !== 1) {
    throw 'variable has to be an object with a single property'
  }
  return variableToXml(object)
}

function variableToXml(variable, arrayItemPropertyName = null) {
  if (Array.isArray(variable)) {
    return variable.reduce((xml, propertyValue) => {
      const value = variableToXml(propertyValue)
      return `${xml}<${arrayItemPropertyName}>${value}</${arrayItemPropertyName}>`
    }, '')
  }
  if (variable instanceof Object) {
    return Object.entries(variable).reduce((xml, [propertyName, propertyValue]) => {
      const value = variableToXml(propertyValue, propertyName )
      const tag = propertyValue instanceof Array ? value : `<${propertyName}>${value}</${propertyName}>`
      return `${xml}${tag}`
    }, '')
  }
  return variable
}
```