# Is there any way to create an XML file with an html form data with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, xml, forms

I got a massive html form. I need the form data to be sent to an XML file every time I click the submit button. I already have each form input valueinside a big array which looks like this:

`0: "2"
1: "105920808"
2: "Carlos Briceño"
3: "212135"
4: "cbrice@femw.com"
5: "3213asdasdas"
6: "cmbriceno@gmail.com"
7: "87047866"
8: "87047866"
9: "1"
10: "55"
11: "8"
12: "Urbanizacion Las Lomas"
13: "Alto de Guadalupe, Urbanización las Lomas"
14: "324131"
15: "pass1 "
16: "444444444444"
17: "1231"
18: "321"
19: "32"
20: "1"
21: "1"
22: "98"
23: "Carlos"
24: "0"
25: "cmbriceno@gmail.com"
26: "24402969"
27: "87047866"
28: "0"
29: "0"
30: "0"
31: ""
32: ""
33: "1231132"
34: "Cambiar AE"
35: "02"
36: "CRC"
37: "01"
38: "565.28"
39: "01"
40: (9) ["1", "123456", "1", "I", "100000", "Linea 1", "", "", "08"]
41: (9) ["1", "10101", "1", "Alc", "20000", "linea 2 ", "10", "", "08"]
42: "This is a test"
43: "118000"
44: ""
45: ""
46: ""
47: ""
48: ""
49: "118000"
50: ""
51: ""
52: "2000"
53: "118000"
54: "116000"
55: ""
56: ""
57: "133340"`

All I want to do is to convert this array to a XML with the propper structure. Have been searching for hours for something similar but didn't find the solution.

Comment: I believe that your question is related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788722/json-to-xml-using-javascript

Comment: Should that be inside an array? Would it not be better to store it as object? Then use some library like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js (just the first result from google)

Comment: if you already have the array, all you need is to run through the array with a simple for loop and structure your data the way you want it in xml (add <item> around it or whatever). add a header at the top, output it to the browser or a file and you're done. read up on xml file structure on https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ - no library needed.

Comment: Thank you all guys, I'll try every of the solutions and let you know which worked the best for me

Comment: I'm still triyin to do it. don't you know the way?

Answer (score 0):

Would tell something like this could be valid XML, but it is probably missing field names.

```js
var data = {0: "2", 1: "105920808", 2: "Carlos Briceño", 3: "212135", 4: "cbrice@femw.com", 5: "3213asdasdas", 6: "cmbriceno@gmail.com", 7: "87047866", 8: "87047866", 9: "1", 10: "55", 11: "8", 12: "Urbanizacion Las Lomas", 13: "Alto de Guadalupe, Urbanización las Lomas", 14: "324131", 15: "pass1 ", 16: "444444444444", 17: "1231", 18: "321", 19: "32", 20: "1", 21: "1", 22: "98", 23: "Carlos", 24: "0", 25: "cmbriceno@gmail.com", 26: "24402969", 27: "87047866", 28: "0", 29: "0", 30: "0", 31: "", 32: "", 33: "1231132", 34: "Cambiar AE", 35: "02", 36: "CRC", 37: "01", 38: "565.28", 39: "01", 40: ["1", "123456", "1", "I", "100000", "Linea 1", "", "", "08"], 41: ["1", "10101", "1", "Alc", "20000", "linea 2 ", "10", "", "08"], 42: "This is a test", 43: "118000", 44: "", 45: "", 46: "", 47: "", 48: "", 49: "118000", 50: "", 51: "", 52: "2000", 53: "118000", 54: "116000", 55: "", 56: "", 57: "133340" };
function print2XML(data, y) {
    var res = '';
    for(var x in data) {
        var idx = y ? (y + '.' + x) : x;
        if (data[x].constructor == Array) {
            res += '<Item' + idx + '>\n' + print2XML(data[x], idx) + '</Item' + idx + '>\n';
        }
        else res += '<Item' + idx + '>' + data[x] + '</Item' + idx + '>\n';
    }
    return res;
}
console.log('<yourXMLdata>\n' + print2XML(data) + '</yourXMLdata>');
document.write(('<yourXMLdata>\n' + print2XML(data) + '</yourXMLdata>').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;').replace(/\n/g,'<br>'));
document.close();
```