# How to convert a dictionary to xml in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to convert a list of dictionary to XML or JSON string in javascript, how could I do this?
the following is the sample list of dictionary:

```
var listItems= [
{'Code Etablissement':'1234', 'No Dossier Patient':'5','Date admission':'14/08/2000','DateSortie':'14/08/2001','Specialite':'Médecine',},
{'Code Etablissement':'1234', 'No Dossier Patient':'10','Date admission':'12/12/1992','DateSortie':'12/12/1992','Specialite':'Chirurgie',},
{'Code Etablissement':'2346', 'No Dossier Patient':'8','Date admission':'03/03/2003','DateSortie':'05/03/2003','Specialite':'Médecine',},
{'Code Etablissement':'2346', 'No Dossier Patient':'1','Date admission':'11/11/1997','DateSortie':'12/12/1997','Specialite':'Orthopédie',},
{'Code Etablissement':'2346', 'No Dossier Patient':'3','Date admission':'12/04/1995','DateSortie':'30/12/1995','Specialite':'Médecine',},
{'Code Etablissement':'3980', 'No Dossier Patient':'5','Date admission':'14/02/2000','DateSortie':'14/03/2000','Specialite':'Médecine',},
{'Code Etablissement':'3980', 'No Dossier Patient':'5','Date admission':'01/01/2001','DateSortie':'01/02/2001','Specialite':'Médecine',},
{'Code Etablissement':'3980', 'No Dossier Patient':'9','Date admission':'03/04/1995','DateSortie':'08/04/1995','Specialite':'Orthopédie',},
{'Code Etablissement':'3980', 'No Dossier Patient':'7','Date admission':'27/11/1999','DateSortie':'04/12/1999','Specialite':'Chirurgie',},
{'Code Etablissement':'3980', 'No Dossier Patient':'10','Date admission':'28/04/1997','DateSortie':'05/05/1999','Specialite':'Chirurgie',},
{'Code Etablissement':'4177', 'No Dossier Patient':'3','Date admission':'03/08/2001','DateSortie':'05/12/2001','Specialite':'Médecine',},
{'Code Etablissement':'4177', 'No Dossier Patient':'3','Date admission':'02/02/2002','DateSortie':'23/02/2002','Specialite':'Orthopédie',},
{'Code Etablissement':'7306', 'No Dossier Patient':'2','Date admission':'23/05/1998','DateSortie':'27/05/1998','Specialite':'Orthopédie',},
```

];

Comment: This depends on the desired XML structure. You have to define this first. Maybe this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788722/json-to-xml-using-javascript

Comment: What if I want to convert to JSON?

Comment: Then you'd use [`JSON.stringify(listItems)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Your data is already JSON. Dictionary is an expression used in Python, in JavaScript we call this JSON.