# Convert JSON to and old XML format

Tags: javascript, json, xml, serialization

I want to convert:

```js
{
  Employer: {
    Name: 'Sample',
    Age: 23
  }
}
```

To:

```xml
<EMPLOYER NAME="Sample" AGE="23"></EMPLOYER>
```

Is this possible? Or if you can suggest an npm package I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: That's a little bit tricky... how will that converter choose between creating new nodes or setting data as params? I don't think there is something generic for you.

Comment: Yes I am having a really hard time too. The big problem is it comes from a third party api so I have no other choice but to work with it. I think its a very old XML format.

Comment: I would google it a little bit before doing something by myself, but if there is no other way, I would use regexp and create a custom serializer/converter for that case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788722/json-to-xml-using-javascript Hope this will help to u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Find XML nodes `<element><\element>`

You can use this regular expression to match the XML nodes

```js
const regex = /['"]?(\w+)['"]?[ ]?:[ ]?{(.[^}]+)}/gms;
```

Regexp101 Debug link: https://regex101.com/r/71cphG/3

```js
const findNodes = (source) => {
    const regexNodes = /['"]?(\w+)['"]?[ ]?:[ ]?{(.[^}]+)}/gms;

    let nodes = [];
    while (m = regexNodes.exec(str)) {
        let nodeName = m[1]
        let nodeBody = m[2]

        nodes.push({ name: nodeName, body: nodeBody });
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

## Find XML node params `age=20`

You can match node params with a regular expression like this:

```js
const regex = /\s+(\w+) ?: ?['"]?(.[^'^"\n]+)['"]?/gms;
```

Regexp101 Debug link: https://regex101.com/r/upMtcz/1

```js
const generateNode = (nodeName, jsonBody) => {
    const regexParams = /\s+(\w+) ?: ?['"]?(.[^'^"\n]+)['"]?/gms;

    let result = `<${nodeName}`;
    while (matches = regexParams.exec(jsonBody)) {
        let param = `${matches[1]}=${matches[2]}`;
        result += ` ${param}`;
    }
    result += `></${nodeName}>`

    return result;
}
```

## Print results

```js
const findNodes = (source) => {
    const regexNodes = /['"]?(\w+)['"]?[ ]?:[ ]?{(.[^}]+)}/gms;

    let nodes = [];
    while (m = regexNodes.exec(str)) {
        let nodeName = m[1]
        let nodeBody = m[2]

        nodes.push({ name: nodeName, body: nodeBody });
    }
    return nodes;
}

const generateNode = (nodeName, jsonBody) => {
    const regexParams = /\s+(\w+) ?: ?['"]?(.[^'^"\n]+)['"]?/gms;

    let result = `<${nodeName}`;
    while (matches = regexParams.exec(jsonBody)) {
        let param = `${matches[1]}=${matches[2]}`;
        result += ` ${param}`;
    }
    result += `></${nodeName}>`

    return result;
}

const str = `{
    "Employer" : {
      Name: 'Sample',
      Age: 23
    },
  Employer: {
      Name: 'Sample',
      Age: 23
    },
  Employer: {
      Name: 'Sample',
      Age: 23
    }
  }`;

findNodes(str)
  .map(({ name, body }) => generateNode(name, body))
  .forEach(element => console.log(element))
```

Comment: I have added a few code examples for you, as I said before, I would google for a better approach if there is any.